# How to cast in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to save a Double variable in an Int variable but I don't know how to do it.
in Java I use this:

*double doubleNumber = (int)intNumber*

Comment: That code sample doesn't make sense. Did you mean: `int intNumber = (int)doubleNumber`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toDouble()` method

```
    /**
     * Converts this [Int] value to [Double].
     *
     * The resulting `Double` value represents the same numerical value as this `Int`.
     */
    public override fun toDouble(): Double
```

And the coude should be like this :

```
val intNumber: Int = 2
val doubleNumber: Double = intNumber.toDouble()
```